# MSB3073 exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Error 102  error MSB3073: The command "copy C:\Users\Bike Simulation\Desktop\testing_dll\DrivingSimulator_DLL\example\DrivingSimulatorTextClient....\bin\VS2010\Win32\DrivingSimulatorProxy.dll C:\Users\Bike Simulation\Desktop\testing_dll\DrivingSimulator_DLL\example\DrivingSimulatorTextClient\bin\VS2010\Win32\Release\
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
132 5  DrivingSimulatorTextClient

I have seen the forums for the MSB3073 error, but i am unable to fix the problem on my code.
It works on a another system, but when I try to run the code on my new PC, it pops this error.

The code project is built on a sample project given by the software developer.

```
<Target Name="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">
<Message Text="Description: %(PostBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
<Exec Command="%(PostBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
```

I get directed to this line on the Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

Comment: The command which exits with code 1 seems to be *copy* not VCEnd? Are those directory names correct and do they exist? Also this doesn't have much to do with C++.

Comment: The file is in "C:\Users\Bike Simulation\Desktop\testing_dll\DrivingSimulator_DLL\example\DrivingSimulatorTextClient\bin\VS2010\Win32\Release"

Comment: @AshwathNarayan What’s detail of that command? (project properties=>Build Events), the project folder is in desktop, try put your project to other disk (e.g. D:\\)

Comment: @s09 the system has only 1 partition

Comment: @s09 the post build has the command   copy $(SolutionDir)..\..\bin\VS2010\$(Platform)\DrivingSimulatorProxy.dll $(OutDir)

Comment: @Please delete the bin/debug or release folder, and then re-open your project, recompile it again. Check the result. In addition, if it works well in another system, please compare the project property in two Environments, like the output path or the build events settings.

Comment: @AshwathNarayan Ok, please try to create a new folder in C disk, then put your solution file on it, then try again.

Comment: @s09 Thank you, moving it to the C disk fixed it.

Comment: I was getting the same error using Visual Studio 2017. The compiler was unable to copy a dll to a folder. Later Found that the directory is ReadOnly. Unchecking the ReadOnly option and re-building the project helped me.
Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comment, my solution of **move solution folder to C disk** fixes that issue.

Comment: What does that even mean? What if your setup has a required location / changes depending on your team's usernames?

Comment: SOLUTION: Move the whole project folder to a different location on the C drive then reload the project and rebuild.
It solved my issue but I still do not understand why it works.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error using Visual Studio 2017. The compiler was unable to copy a dll to a folder. Later Found that the directory is ReadOnly. **Unchecking the ReadOnly option** and re-building the project helped me.
Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem happened to me with Visual Studio 2017. Solution was on C drive, unchecking ReadOnly flag didn't solve the issue. What helped was to **run Visual Studio as an Administrator**.

When you run as Administrator you will see this in the corner of Visual Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I figured that I'll answer anyway, since I had the same problem.

The root cause of the error in this case is that there is a space (" ") in the directory or file name (in this case: "Bike Simulation").

Hence, the command "copy" is unable to process its parameters correctly. Easiest way to fix this is to rename the directories.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.
The compiler failing with security error,PSSecurityException as **UnauthorizedAccess** error as shown below.
[image]

Unblock the file and re-building the project helped me. Hope this helps anyone.